# How to attach provider properly to the reactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I wanted to try redux with a framework 7 react template. I installed redux, react-redux on top of the teamplate and copy paste all code from reduxjs todoList example into my template, but I have problem with provider integration.

I get **Target container is not a DOM element** error for below code

```
// Mount React App
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  React.createElement(App),
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Initialy it was like this and it was working, I only added provider

```
// Mount React App
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App),
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```js
// Mount React App
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`<App />` [gets compiled to `React.createElement(App)`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwQQDmAED0B8Q&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=), so you only need the first `Provider` part of your code since `App` is a child to `Provider`.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```